# Creating the "Invalid or Stale Connection found in the Connection Cache" local Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, jdbc

I would like to know how to tweak my local Oracle DB settings to get this error through my web application. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
I altered the user's profile:

```
ALTER PROFILE cashnet LIMIT 
    SESSIONS_PER_USER          UNLIMITED 
    CPU_PER_SESSION            UNLIMITED 
    CPU_PER_CALL               3000 
    CONNECT_TIME               1 
    IDLE_TIME                  1
    LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION  DEFAULT 
    LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL     1000 
    PRIVATE_SGA                15K
    COMPOSITE_LIMIT            5000000;

protected Properties getDefaultConnectionProps()
{
    Properties prop = new Properties ();`
    prop.setProperty("MinLimit", "1");     // the cache size is 5 at least 
    prop.setProperty("MaxLimit", "1");
    prop.setProperty("InitialLimit", "2"); // create 3 connections at startup
    prop.setProperty("InactivityTimeout", "1");    //  seconds
    prop.setProperty("TimeToLiveTimeout","30"); 
    prop.setProperty("AbandonedConnectionTimeout", "900");  //  seconds
    prop.setProperty("MaxStatementsLimit", "10");
    prop.setProperty("ValidateConnection","true");
    prop.setProperty("PropertyCheckInterval", "60"); // seconds
    System.out.println("[OracleConnector2.getDefaultConnectionProps] Setting properties");
    prop.setProperty("oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT", "1");
    return prop;
}

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
{
    OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ocpds
        = (OracleConnectionPoolDataSource)_pooledConnections.get(getConectionId());
    if(ocpds == null){
        ocpds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ocpds.setURL(_url);
        ocpds.setUser(_user);
        ocpds.setPassword(_password);
        Properties prop = getDefaultConnectionProps();
        if (_readtimeout != null){
            _connectionProps.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout", _readtimeout + "000");
        }
        else{
            _connectionProps.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout", "20000");
        }
        // clean up connection props for OAS
        _connectionProps.remove("oracle.net.encryption_client");
        _connectionProps.remove("oracle.net.encryption_types_client");
        _connectionProps.remove("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client");
        _connectionProps.remove("oracle.net.crypto_checksum_types_client");
        prop.putAll(_connectionProps);
        ocpds.setConnectionCacheProperties (prop);  // set properties
        _pooledConnections.put(getConectionId(),ocpds);
    }
    System.out.println("[OracleConnector2.getConnection] Setting timeout");
    if (_logintimeout != null){
        ocpds.setLoginTimeout(Integer.parseInt(_logintimeout.trim()));
    }else{
        ocpds.setLoginTimeout(10);
    }
    PooledConnection pc = ocpds.getPooledConnection(_user,_password);
    return pc.getConnection();
}
```

Comment: Might killing the session lead to this?

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for responding. Please see above, I tried killing the sessions, but it's still creating new ones.

Comment: @AlexPoole : Sorry I just saw my mistake there, I'll alter the statement to remove the unlimited session and then give it a shot.

Comment: Does the profile change mean you have a working solution? If so you should accept Justin's answer (not repeat it in the question), and if not you should say what doesn't now work.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your help with this, the combination of tweaking the profile and deleting the sessions gave me the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various approaches.  The simplest would be to kill the database sessions for the connections that are currently in the connection pool.  If, for some reason, you want to force that error to occur on an ongoing basis, I suppose that you could [modify the profile](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm) for the Oracle database user to set an `IDLE_TIME` (assuming that your application maintains connections in the connection pool for a reasonable period of time).

Comment: Hello Justin,   Thank you very much for taking the time to help me  out.  Please see what I have attempted currently with my profile tweaking:   `ALTER PROFILE cashnet LIMIT 
   SESSIONS_PER_USER          UNLIMITED 
   CPU_PER_SESSION            UNLIMITED 
   CPU_PER_CALL               3000 
   CONNECT_TIME               1 
   IDLE_TIME                  1
   LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION  DEFAULT 
   LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL     1000 
   PRIVATE_SGA                15K
   COMPOSITE_LIMIT            5000000; `

Comment: Thanks Justin for your help, I have another question but I'll open a new thread for that.